# How can I apply JS file I made to C# Cefsharp winform?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I used to use Selenium and now trying to do automation test with JS file i made but, cannot open the file on browser.

I want to run a js function name.

This is the part of the source

C#

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       

        try
        { 

        Text = "Browser";
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        ResizeBegin += (s, e) => SuspendLayout();
        ResizeEnd += (s, e) => ResumeLayout(true);

        Load += OnLoad;

    }

    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateBrowser();
    }

    private async void CreateBrowser()
    {
        while (waitprocess)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

        waitprocess = true;
        CefSettings setting = new CefSettings();
        setting.UserAgent = "MOBILE USERAGENT";

        try
        {
            setting.CachePath = "Cache/" + "1";
        }
        catch
        {
            setting.CachePath = "Cache/test";
        }

        Cef.Initialize(setting);
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("TEST WEB SITE")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };

        toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnBrowserFrameLoadEnd;
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnBrowserLoadingStateChanged;
        browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
        browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
        browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", new BoundObject());

    }
```

JS file that i made is usually a function that generates a click event...

For example...

```
function Cri_Element_Click_Tab(element, xpos)
{
  var eml = element;

  var nTenPercentX = parseInt(eml.offsetWidth - (eml.offsetWidth / 10));
  var nTenPercentY = parseInt(eml.offsetHeight - (eml.offsetHeight / 10));


  var addx = CriGenerateRandomNumber( nTenPercentX);
  var addy = CriGenerateRandomNumber( nTenPercentY);

  eml.focus();
  var x = getOffset( eml ).left; 
  var y = getOffset( eml ).top;

  if(x < 0)
  {
      var elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      x= elemRect.left;
  }

  var mousex = window.screenX + xpos;
  var mousey = window.screenY + y + addy;


//alert(mousex);

  criX = parseInt(mousex);
  criY = parseInt(mousey);

  targetElement = eml;
  fireTouchStart();
  fireTouchEnd();

  window.CriSendMousePointClick(criX,criY);

}
```

Comment: Have you read the `FAQ`? Your `JS` isn't particularly large, you can simply execute the code. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-methods-from-net

Comment: These functions are more than 100. I want to run a js function name.

Comment: What's more than 100? Declare a function then execute it. Very straight forward. I prefer to wrap code in anonymous closures.

Comment: For example
    function click_1(){..} 
    function click_2(){..}
    function click_3(){..}
    ...function click_100(){...}

Comment: Too many functions in this way, so I was looking the other way.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, have a go.

Comment: Are you actually experiencing a problem or just assuming you will? I've seen people execute some rather large script blocks, much bigger than what your suggesting.

Comment: If you actually run into a problem you can register a `ResourceHandler` that represents your script, then execute some `JS` to load that file. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L310 make sure you use the same domain so you don't get cross domain restrictions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll try this one